# Convert string of hexadecimal to decimal in c

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, hex, osdev

I am writing an operating system in C and assembly, and in implementing the EXT2 file system I have encountered a problem. I need to convert FOUR bytes of hexadecimal to decimal in c. An example would be to convert `00 00 01`(`10000`) to `65536`.I need to convert to decimal,because parsing the super block requires all values to be in decimal. Most specifically the ext2 fs I'm working on is here:

```
#include "ext2.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
long hex2dec(unsigned const char *hex){
long ret = 0;
int i = 0;
while(hex[i] != 0){
    //if(hex[i] >= 0x00 && hex[i] <= 0x09)
    //  ret+=(10 * i) * hex[i];
}
//kprintf("\n");
return ret;
}
char *strsep(char *buf,int offset,int num){
char *ret = malloc(1024);
int j = 0;
int i = offset;
int end = (offset + num);
int i1 = 0;
while(i1 < num){
    ///kstrcat(ret,&buf[i]);
    ret[i1] = buf[i];
    i++;
    i1++;
}
return ret;
}
int get_partition(partnum){
if(partnum > 4)
    return -1;
//int i = (12 * partnum);
int i = 0;
if(partnum == 1)
    i = 190;
else if(partnum == 2)
    i = 206;
else if(partnum == 3)
    i = 222;
else
    i = 190;
int ret = 0;
char *buf = malloc(1024);
ata_read_master(buf,1,0x00);
ret = buf[(i + 2)];
return ret;
}
int _intlen(int i){
int ret = 0;
while(i){
    ret++;
    i/=10;
}
return ret;
}
int _hex2int(char c){
if(c == '0')
    return 0;
else if(c == '1')
    return 1;
else if(c == '2')
    return 2;
else if(c == '3')
    return 3;
    else if(c == '4')
            return 4;
    else if(c == '5')
            return 5;
    else if(c == '6')
            return 6;
    else if(c == '7')
            return 7;
    else if(c == '8')
            return 8;
    else if(c == '9')
            return 9;
    else if(c == 'A')
            return 10;
    else if(c == 'B')
            return 11;
    else if(c == 'C')
            return 12;
    else if(c == 'D')
            return 13;
    else if(c == 'E')
            return 14;
    else if(c == 'F')
            return 15;


}
int hex2int(char c){
int i = c;

}
int comb(const char *str,int n){
int i = 0;
int ret = 0;
while(i < n){
    //if(str[i] == 0x01)
    //  kprintf("(:");
    /*int j = str[i];
    int k = 0;
    int m = 0;
    if(j < 10)
        j*=10;
    else
        while(j > 0){
            k+=(10 ^ (_intlen(j) - m)) * j % 10;
            m++;
            j/=10;
        }
    //kprintf("%d",j);
    //if(j == 1)
    //  kprintf("(:");*/
    i++;
}

//ret = (char)ret;
ret = (char)str
int ret = 0;
int i = 0;
char *s = malloc(1024);
/*while(i < n){

    //kstrcat(s,&((char*)buf[i]));
    n++;
}*/

return ret;
//kprintf("\n");
//return ret;
}
struct ext2_superblock *parse_sblk(int partnum){
int i = get_partition(partnum);
if(i > 0)
    kprintf("[EXT2_SUPERBLOCK]Found partition!\n");
else
    i = 0;
struct ext2_superblock *ret;
struct ext2_superblock retnp;
char *buf = malloc(1024);
int i1 = 0;
//char *tmpbuf = malloc(4);
/*if(i != 0)
    ata_read_master(buf,((i * 4)/256),0x00);
else{
    kprintf("[WRN]: Looking for superblock at offset 1024\n");
    ata_read_master(buf,4,0x00);
}*/
ata_read_master(buf,2,0x00);
const char *cmp = strsep(buf,0,4);


retnp.ninode = comb(strsep(buf,0,4),4);

    retnp.nblock = comb(strsep(buf,4,4),4);
    retnp.nsblock = comb(strsep(buf,8,4),4);
    retnp.nunallocb = comb(strsep(buf,12,4),4);
    retnp.nunalloci = comb(strsep(buf,16,4),4);
    retnp.supernum = comb(strsep(buf,20,4),4);
    retnp.leftshiftbs = comb(strsep(buf,24,4),4);
    retnp.leftshiftfs = comb(strsep(buf,28,4),4);
    retnp.numofblockpg= comb(strsep(buf,32,4),4);
 //   retnp.numofffpbg= comb(strsep(buf,36,4));
    retnp.numoffpbg = comb(strsep(buf,36,4),4);
    retnp.numofinpbg = comb(strsep(buf,40,4),4);
    retnp.lastmount = comb(strsep(buf,44,4),4);
    retnp.lastwrite = comb(strsep(buf,48,4),4);
    retnp.fsckpass = comb(strsep(buf,52,2),2);
    retnp.fsckallow = comb(strsep(buf,54,2),2);
    retnp.sig = comb(strsep(buf,56,2),2);
    retnp.state = comb(strsep(buf,58,2),2);
    retnp.erroropp = comb(strsep(buf,60,2),2);
    retnp.minorpor = comb(strsep(buf,52,2),2);
    retnp.ptimefsck = comb(strsep(buf,64,4),4);
    retnp.inter = comb(strsep(buf,68,4),4);
    retnp.osid = comb(strsep(buf,72,4),4);
retnp.mpv = comb(strsep(buf,76,4),4);
    retnp.uid = comb(strsep(buf,80,2),2);
retnp.gid = comb(strsep(buf,82,2),2);
ret = &retnp;
return ret;
i1 = 0;


}
```

If there is anyway of avoiding conversion and successfully implementing ext2 I would be glad to hear it.  I would prefer it to be in c,but assembly is also okay.

Comment: Please post the relevant code inline as text and not as links

Comment: @EdChum okay,I will in a sec

Comment: "I need to convert to decimal,because parsing the super block requires all values to be in decimal." I think you are at a very wron level of abstraction. I don't think you need to parse or convert anything here. Just take the values as they are, maybe combine them to form values longer than 1 byte. But I really don't see the need for conversion to or drom text.

Comment: Where is the target `00 00 01` in the code?

Comment: @MikeCAT it's meant to be generic,but that is in a 1GB hard drive image,so I figured it would be too big to post

Comment: OK, you are asking how to implement `hex2dec`, right?

Comment: @ZachS If you think that e.g. `int x = 4711;` somehow puts a "decimal" value in `x`, I believe you're way into the deep end writing an operating system and a file system driver. That's just not true, and your question makes little sense (as pointed out by @glglgl). Converting four packed bytes into an integer has nothing to do with "converting hex to decimal".

Comment: @unwind Firstly the four packed bytes are in hexadecimal format when read into the string from my ata reader,secondly I Know that integers are positive and negative numbers,and pointers point to memory,etc. Secondly I never thought that it was a decimal value. I just need to convert  from the character pointer to an integer. for example on the ext2 superblock the 1st 3 bytes are made to point the number of inodes in the system,but they are in hexadecimal format. They are read into my string as char str[] = {0x00,0x00,0x01}. I need to get that to decimal format or at least int

Comment: @ZachS That is raw binary data, it is not in hexadecimal format, that is just a property of how you happen to view the data. `char str[] = { 0, 0, 1 };` is the exact same data but in decimal.

Comment: @unwind But that's not how I want it. I need all of the characters "combined" to be 10000. That's where the problem arises. I know I can express string like that,but I need some way to read all in put it into a single char or int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this:

```
const uint8_t bytes[] = { 0, 0, 1 };
```

and you want to consider that the bytes of a (24-bit) unsigned integer in little-endian order, you can convert to the actual integer using:

```
const uint32_t value = ((uint32_t) bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[1] << 8) | bytes[0];
```

This will set `value` equal to 65536.

Comment: Thank you i'll try that when I get home

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::istringstream` or `sscanf` instead of writing your own.

```
char const * hex_text[] = "0x100";
const std::string hex_str(hex_text);
std::istringstream text_stream(hex_str);
unsigned int value;
text_stream >> std::ios::hex >> value;
std::cout << "Decimal value of 0x100: " << value << "\n";
```

Or using `sscanf`:

```
sscanf(hex_text, "0x%X", &value);
std::cout << "Decimal value of 0x100: " << value << "\n";
```

A good idea is to search your C++ reference for existing functions or search the internet, before writing your own.

To roll your own:

```
unsigned int hex2dec(const std::string& hex_text)
{
  unsigned int value = 0U;
  const unsigned int length = hex_text.length();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
    const char c = hex_text[i];
    if ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
    {
       value = value * 16 + (c - '0');
    }
    else
    {
      c = toupper(c);
      if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z'))
      {
         value = value * 16 + (c - 'A') + 10;
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

To convert to use C-style character strings, change the parameter type and use `strlen` for the length.

Comment: I don't have access to a c library

Comment: Most modern compilers, including those for embedded systems, have these kinds of libraries.

Comment: And the hex text is not so much of a string if it where written as a string it would look like "\0\0\1" . However I am thinking of putting it into a string,but I will do that when i'm at home

Comment: Are you trying to convert one or more bytes to a larger hex value?  If so, what is the byte ordering, Big Endian or Little Endian?

Comment: I believe it is little endian but when I get home i'll make sure